# Dynamics ax 2012 compiler warning when seting smmOpportunityTable to common

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

A class can receive either a VendTable, CustTable or smmOpportunityTable record.

For one instance a CustTable record was usually received, and a new requirement brings an  smmOpportunityTable into play, so I’m using a common record to catch it with this piece of code:

(some other stuff happens earlier in the code to set the custTable record).

`commonParty = custTable.RecId != 0 ? custTable : smmOpportunityTable;`

The problem is, the above line of code gives a compile warning “Operand types are not compatible with the operator.”; faulting on the smmOpportunityTable.

My question, why can’t I set an instance of smmOpportunityTable to common?  Surely its of base type common?  Any ideas how to resolve the warning?

I’m developing in Dynamics Ax 2012 R1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is actually just because the compiler seems to be incorrectly handling the use of the ternary operator.

To remove the warning, you can just rewrite as:

```
if (custTable)
    commonParty = custTable;
else
    commonParty = smmOpportunityTable;
```

`if (custTable)` is the same as `if (custTable.RecId != 0)`.  It literally just checks if the `RecId` field is populated.

And I might be confused with what you're trying to do in code, but for the other side of the assignment the convention is usually as follows:

```
switch (common.TableId)
{
    case tableNum(CustTable):
        custTable = common as CustTable;
        break;

    case tableNum(smmOpportunityTable):
        smmOpportunityTable = common as smmOpportunityTable;
        break;

    default:
        throw error(strFmt(Error::wrongUseOfFunction(funcName())));
}
```

Comment: Yip, I did write the switch to get rid of the warning.  Still annoyed that the compiler can interpret the custTable as a common but not the smmOpportunities table...  Thanks though!

Comment: You could try with parenthesis `commonParty = (custTable.RecId != 0) ? custTable : smmOpportunityTable;` and see if that might work?